# converting text to speech java code

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I dont understand this syntax error , `insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation  Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement      at demojsapi.main(demojsapi.java:46)`

I am actually working on a java project converting text to speesh with this code :

```
import javax.speech.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.speech.synthesis.*;

public class demojsapi
{
    String speaktext;

    public void dospeak(String speak,String  voicename)
    {
        speaktext=speak;
        String voiceName =voicename;
        try
        {
            SynthesizerModeDesc desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(null,"general",  Locale.US,null,null);
            Synthesizer synthesizer =  Central.createSynthesizer(desc);
            synthesizer.allocate();
            synthesizer.resume();
            desc = (SynthesizerModeDesc)  synthesizer.getEngineModeDesc();
            Voice[] voices = desc.getVoices();
            Voice voice = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < voices.length; i++)
            {
                if (voices[i].getName().equals(voiceName))
                {
                    voice = voices[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            synthesizer.getSynthesizerProperties().setVoice(voice);
            synthesizer.speakPlainText(speaktext, null);
            synthesizer.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);
            synthesizer.deallocate();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String message = " missing speech.properties in " + System.getProperty("user.home") + "\n";
            System.out.println(""+e);
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        demojsapi obj=new demojsapi(); obj.despeak("shit","kevin16");
    }
}
```

Comment: format the code please. nobodys is going to read through that

Comment: please just give the appropriate amount of code relevant for the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `despeak` method does not exist. You should call `dospeak` instead and with regular quotes:

```
obj.dospeak("foo", "kevin16");
```

Comment: yes I changed that before I posted the code but same problem  The method dospeak(String, String) in the type demojsapi is not applicable for the arguments (String)
 Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

Comment: The problem is with the quotes you are using. Can you change them to regular quotes instead?

Comment: sorry man it was all about quotes well thx a lot but steal have another problem ... java.lang.NullPointerException
 missing speech.properties in C:\Users\USER

Comment: Properties are not being found. See this [link](http://www.ryan-h.com/uncategorized/java-speech-jsapi-freetts/).

Answer (score 5):

please Download freetts-1.2.2-bin from google from given link and

http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetts/?source=directory

try my program in net beans

do not forget to add all jar files into your library folder
code is given below. Its working ..
my method ---

```
private static final String VOICENAME = "kevin16";                                        
void mySpeak()
{
Voice voice;
VoiceManager vm = VoiceManager.getInstance();
voice = vm.getVoice(VOICENAME);
voice.allocate();
try{
voice.speak("Hi Mr Gaur Welcome to VITS. Thanks To choose Us");
}catch(Exception e){}
}
```

call this method from your inner code..

Answer (score 1):

**Very nicely explained Complete procedure with running code -** [Text To Speech in Java Using Freetts](http://tryjustlikethis.blogspot.in/2013/10/text-to-speech-converter-in-java.html#.V15S3NJ97IU)

Working Code :

```
import javax.speech.*;    
import java.util.*;    
import javax.speech.synthesis.*;    

public class Text2Speech    
{    
String speaktext; 
public void dospeak(String speak,String  voicename)    
{    
    speaktext=speak;    
    String voiceName =voicename;    
    try    
    {    
        SynthesizerModeDesc desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(null,"general",  Locale.US,null,null);    
        Synthesizer synthesizer =  Central.createSynthesizer(desc);    
        synthesizer.allocate();    
        synthesizer.resume();     
        desc = (SynthesizerModeDesc)  synthesizer.getEngineModeDesc();     
        Voice[] voices = desc.getVoices();      
        Voice voice = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < voices.length; i++)    
        {    
            if (voices[i].getName().equals(voiceName))    
            {    
                voice = voices[i];    
                break;     
            }     
        }    
        synthesizer.getSynthesizerProperties().setVoice(voice);    
        System.out.print("Speaking : "+speaktext);    
        synthesizer.speakPlainText(speaktext, null);    
        synthesizer.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);    
        synthesizer.deallocate();    
    }    
    catch (Exception e)   
    {    
        String message = " missing speech.properties in " + System.getProperty("user.home") + "\n";    
        System.out.println(""+e);    
        System.out.println(message);    
    }    
}    

public static void main(String[] args)    
{    
    Text2Speech obj=new Text2Speech(); obj.dospeak("Hello i am kevin ","kevin16");    
}    
}
```

Comment: 1) Why is it nice explained there? 2) Put the important content into the answer, rather than just having a link.

Comment: Reference link: Error. Page cannot be displayed. Please contact your service provider for more details. (7)

Comment: Central.createSynthesizer is returning me null everytime :(